# Ctrl Down recorded macro is not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, macro-recorder

The macro I have recorded is not acting as expected.

I  am selecting cell H1 and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>down</kbd> to the next cell with data but it just doesn't seem to move from H1

```
function UntitledMacro1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Auto Print'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setFrozenRows(0);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setFontColor('#ffffff');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Lables'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('T7').activate();
var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSelection();
var currentCell = selection.getCurrentCell();
};
```

Comment: The last two lines of code needs to paste into "Lables" T7, I'm not sure i have to last two lines correct if anyone can help with that

Comment: As the post is stated it this looks more as a complain that should be addressed to Google rather than a proper question for this site. Please [edit] the question to clarify what is this question about, add a brief description of the spreadsheet structure and add some sample data so other people could reproduce the expected behavior.